# Permission denied error when using make all-recursive?

Tags: make, macos, cmake, gnu-make, autotools

I am using autotools and GNU make to build a C library, there is a line

```
all: config.h
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) all-recursive
```

In the Makefile, and I get an error compiling

```
make  all-recursive
make: make: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:427: all] Error 127
```

What's wrong?

Comment: the user you're building with doesn't have permission to read or write to a file. Whatever you do, don't build as root, but: You need to make sure you've got the required privileges on the directory you're building in. Make isn't a modern build system, and among the (bad) old ideas it sticks to is doing the build within the source code directory. I guess your source code directory doesn't belong to you – maybe a simple `cp -r /path/to/sources ~/` might fix that, buy creating a copy you can work with?